# count rows from subquery when grouped by

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, subquery

I need help counting the result of rows in a subquery in MySQL, I have something like this:

```
SELECT t.Name, 
       t.Person,
       (SELECT COUNT(pp.id) FROM pp JOIN account s ON s.id = pp.account WHERE s.person = t.id HAVING SUM(pp.total) >= (i.total - 250))'Total Accounts', 
FROM (SELECT p.id, n.name 'Name', p.name 'Person' 
      FROM names n 
      JOIN person p ON p.id = n.person) t
      JOIN payInfo i
GROUP BY t.Name
```

and I want to get something like this with a GROUP BY in the subquery

```
SELECT t.Name, 
       t.Person,
       (SELECT COUNT(pp.id) FROM pp JOIN account s ON s.id = pp.account WHERE s.person = t.id GROUP BY s.id HAVING SUM(pp.total) >= (i.total - 250))'Total Accounts', 
FROM (SELECT p.id, n.name 'Name', p.name 'Person' 
      FROM names n 
      JOIN person p ON p.id = n.person) t
      JOIN payInfo i
GROUP BY t.Name
```

I got this error:  "Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Comment: Have you got any error?

Comment: Subquery returns more than 1 row